# Google script : Add comments using Drive API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I'm trying to add comments to a cell in my google sheet using google apps script. My sample code works but it does not show comment on the specific cell but I can see it when I click on 'open comments history'. What's wrong with my code?

```
function test(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var fileid = ss.getId();
  insertDriveComment(fileid,"hi","dd@gmail.com");
}
function insertDriveComment(fileId, comment,email) {
  var driveComment = {
    content: comment,
    "author": {
      "kind": "drive#user",
      "displayName": email,
      "isAuthenticatedUser": true,
    },
    page : {p:0,mp:1},
  anchor:{
      'r': 'head',
      'a': [
      {     
        'matrix':
        {
          'c': 3,
          'r': 1,
        }
      }]
    }
  };
  Drive.Comments.insert(driveComment,fileId);  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with your code.

### The anchoring if comments does not work as intended, this has been already reported on [Google's Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/146053105).

I suggest you to "star" the issue to increase visibility and stay up-to-date about its state.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to my notice.